# Why is the dictionary automatically printing without me telling it to?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm messing around with classes and dictionaries trying to understand how to use them better. The idea I came up with was to create a bunch of classes that gave a bunch of different descriptors for some object, I used monsters from D & D, and then create a dictionary with all of those monsters so that I could use the key from the dictionary to load the descriptors from the classes.

```
import dice #a dice module i made
import textwrap

class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Goblin'
        self.desc = 'bla bla bla, I'm not going to type the whole thing.'
        self.health = dice.d8.roll(1) + 1

    def describe(self):
        print self.name
        print self.health, 'other random info not in self.desc'
        print textwrap.fill(self.desc, 60)
```

`goblin = Goblin()`
So there's my class setup. When I put in print goblin.describe() everything worked fine. Then I set up my dictionary:

```
bestiary = {
    'Goblin': goblin.describe()
    }
```

I deleted goblin.describe(), so there was no command telling the program to print anything, but when I run the program, it runs goblin.describe() and shows the chunk of text describing my goblin. My question is why is it doing this and is there a way to make it not do that, so I could independently use goblin.describe() or any_other_monster_I make.describe() and have it pull up the description?

I understand there are probably easier ways to do this, but I'm just trying to figure out *why* it's doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Well you are actually evaluating describe here (calling it)

```
bestiary = {
    'Goblin': goblin.describe()
}
```

You can just try to return the string rather than just printing it:

```
import dice #a dice module i made
import textwrap

class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Goblin'
        self.desc = 'bla bla bla, I''m not going to type the whole thing.'
        self.health = dice.d8.roll(1) + 1

def describe(self):
    return self.name + " " + self.health + " " + 'other random info not in self.desc ' \
           + 'other random info not in self.desc ' + textwrap.fill(self.desc, 60)


goblin = Goblin()

bestiary = {
    'Goblin': goblin.describe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on "When i put in print goblin.describe() everything worked fine." I think you want something like this:

```
def describe(self):
    result = ""
    result += self.name
    result += str(self.health) + ' other random info not in self.desc'
    result += textwrap.fill(self.desc, 60)
    return result
```

I.e. return the description from describe(), don't print it inside the method.

Comment: So even though goblin.describe() is inside of a dictionary, it's still going to be run as if it weren't inside a dictionary?

Comment: bestiary = {'Goblin': goblin.describe()} means: execute goblin.describe() and put the result in the dictionary bestiary under the key 'Goblin'. Alternatively you can put the function itself (not the result of its execution) in the dictionary, just remove the parentheses: bestiary = {'Goblin': goblin.describe}

Comment: Generally speaking, it's more idiomatic to `str.join` an iterable of strings rather than to construct the result using `+=`.

Comment: mgilson, I agree. That's why I wrote "something like this". It doesn't really matter for this question and I wanted to present the idea as simply as possible.

Comment: @Hitstein If a function prints, it will always print.  It doesn't matter where/when the function is being called.  A dictionary does not trap standard out.  Is there a language that you are coming from where functions print contidtionally?

Comment: I'm not coming from any languages, but I understand now. I appreciate everyones inputs.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand there are probably easier ways to do this, but I'm just trying to figure out why it's doing this.

take something like this:

```
def bla():
   print("bla")

def alb():
   return("alb")

bbb = bla()
aaa = alb() #this could be anthing not just "aaa= alb()" it could be something like thing_dict = {'thing': alb() }
```

The `bla` function will print "bla". Printing is a simple way of saying: "it goes to standard out, which is most likely your console" this print is happening before `bla` returns, so it just gets printed and then returns `none` ( because you didn't tell it to return anything) ( ALL FUNCTIONS RETURN NONE UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED)

`bla()` can be re-written as

```
def bla():
    print("bla")
    return None
```

And it would do the EXACT same thing.

The `alb` function returns "alb" because you explicitly told it to.

If you do `type(bbb)` you will get `NoneType` because `bla()` didn't return anything

If you do `type(aaa)` you will get `str` because the `alb()` function returned "alb"

If you do `print(bbb)` you will get `None` because that's what `bla()` returned (you didn't define a return, so it returned `None`)

If you do `print(aaa)` you will get "alb" because you told `alb()` to return that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do. I really did not understand what you meant by "deleted goblin.describe()". Do you mean you removed it from the dict, or that you removed that method from the class? In either case, maybe some caching? delete any .pyc files in your working directory and try again.

Or maybe you're trying to add the method to the dictionary, so that you can call describe at some later point? You can just add the method then instead of calling it (remember, in python, everything, including methods, are objects). Therefore, you can perfectly do:

```
goblin = Goblin()
bestiary = { 'Goblin' : goblin.describe }
# and later call 'describe' as follows
bestiary['Goblin']()

# though personally I'd opt for the following which is more legible
goblin = Goblin()
bestiary = { 'Goblin' : goblin }
bestiary['Goblin'].describe()
```